# Sum of Vlookups advice

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, vlookup, google-sheets-api

*I have a column "Uni"* 
E.g.

```
     Person    Uni        Round 1 Round 2 Total Rank
     Leia      Notts      5         5      10   
     Hailey    Notts      6         5      11
     Bobby     Bath       8         1      9
     James     Liverpool  9         1      10
```

*Then another table:*

```
University   Total Score           Rank 
Notts         =sum(vlookup(...))
Bath          =sum(vlookup(...))
```

Currently, my formula returns the 'first' lookup of the keyword - e.g. for notts, it returns '10' - rather than looking up the 10 and the 11 and summing them.

How do  **I make it lookup and sum both values**?

My current formula is `=sum(vlookup(S7,B$3:Q$40,15,FALSE))` where S7 is "*Notts"*, range, index column 15 is *"total score"*

There's about 8-10 of each university.

Answer (score 1):

Vlookup only returns one value, you can't sum over that.
Maybe use instead something like 
=SUMIF(B$3:B$40,S7,$P3:$P40)